# Memcached error: SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY

Tags: memcached

Here is my test code:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '11211';

if (extension_loaded('memcached')) {
    $mc = new Memcached;
    $mc->addServer($host, $port);
    if ($mc->set('test', 'TEST')) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo $mc->getResultCode();
        echo $mc->getResultMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo 'no_memcached';
}
```

The output is:

> 47 SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY

SELinux is disabled, I've also tried to turn off `tcp_nodelay` in nginx.conf and tried different types of host (127.0.0.1 and localhost) and ports.

I've read this question - [How to debug memcached "SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY" errors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/470951/how-to-debug-memcached-server-has-failed-and-is-disabled-until-timed-retry-err)

But nothing helped and I cannot comment, because I have not enough points.

Comment: theres an additional one:
https://serverfault.com/questions/64007/failed-to-connect-to-memcache-host?rq=1
and however, verify that the server is started

Answer (score 1):

It can be different problems why it's not run.

In my case, I realized that memcached service is not started in docker container.

So, first  - check if memcached actually works and check it logs. Try to connect to memcached (on default location)

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

Comment: lsof -i -P :11211 will get better results

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple.

Memcached was installed as a PHP module, but not as a Debian extension.

To install it, just run two commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install memcached
```

Done. All works now.